# How to justify the shape of a curve?

Tags: calculus

Problem:

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions with respect to $x$,  and they are continuous and differential. Now, I need to plot a curve composed of $(f(x),g(x))$, e.g., the curve is the connection of these points $\{(f(x0),g(x0)), (f(x1),g(x1)), (f(x2),g(x2))...\}$

Then, how to justify the shape of this curve? Is it convex or concave? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into interpolation formulas? Look into Lagrange Interpolation.

Comment: I haven't looked into interpolation formulas. This method seems a numerical method. I need to theoretically analyze the shape of the curve. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. So you are just given arbitrary discrete points in space and asked if it is convex or concave? And what do you mean by "justify the shape of this curve?" I think your question is quite vague.

Answer (score 1):

You have a parametric curve,

$$  r(t) = (f(t) , g(t)$$ which is a curve on the plane.

In order to discuss the concavity of this curve with respect to the x-axis, you need to find $$\frac {d^2 y}{dx^2}$$

Note that  $$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {\frac {dy}{dt}}{ \frac {dx}{dt}} = \frac {g'}{f'} $$ using Quotient rule we get,
$$\frac {d^2 y}{dx^2}=\frac {f'g'' -f''g'}{f'^2} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer， it's great.

Comment: You can accept this solution now.